# CASE statement in stored procedure having default null parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure with 4 parameters which need to be null by default.

If I pass any one parameter and set the remaining three to NULL, the procedure output must show all the related data.

Can anyone help me with the syntax?

Comment: http://sqlsentry.tv/the-kitchen-sink-procedure/

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Also known as [catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/). (and a [re-visit](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) by the same author)

Comment: What do you mean by 'all the related data' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to answer without more context, however the statement below will select the first non-null value.  Does this help?

```
SELECT COALESCE(@var1, @var2, @var3, @var4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that helped me in one way